# Cookies to multiple controllers?

Tags: java, angularjs, cookies

We're working on a Spring based application with multiple controllers for various modules such as user authentication, analytics jobs, etc. Our user controller is setting cookies for things like authentication and we are able to retrieve those cookies in the same controller. When we try to grab those cookies in another controller, we are getting a null cookie array.

Our user controller is located on `/application/user/job_name` and another controller is simply `/application/controller/job_name`.

Our request looks like this:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/application/controller/testResponse',
        withCredentials: true,
    })
```

Any ideas as to why we can retrieve cookies from a `HttpServletRequest` object by using `getCookies` in one controller but not in the other?

EDIT: I ended up resolving the problem by ensuring that the path was being set to `/`.

Comment: Which controller is angular and which is Spring? It's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edit above says this as well but the problem ended up being that we had no path set on the cookies. By setting the path to `/` we are able to receive the cookies in all of our Spring controllers.